# How to override an overload Java method in nativescript?

Tags: java, android, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have an Android-Java class that have two overloaded methods

```
package com.test;

public class A{

  public void theMethod(Bitmap bitmap){
    ...
  }

  public void theMethod(int resource){
    ...
  }
}
```

And I am trying to extends the class in a **Nativescript-Angular** program:

```
class ExtendedA extends com.test.A{
    public theMethod(bitmap : android.graphics.Bitmap) : void{
        ...
    }
}
```

but I have this error

```
Property 'theMethod' in type 'ExtendedA' is not assignable to the same property in base type ‘A’.
  Type ‘(bitmap : Bitmap) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (param: Bitmap): void; (param : number): void; }'.
    Types of parameters 'bitmap' and 'param' are incompatible.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Bitmap'.
```

**P.D. I have not the class com.test.A code.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tsconfig.json file you need to make  --[strictFunctionTypes:true](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true
 }
```

**P.S.** if your argument count is different in Class A then Java method overloads are handled by the developer by explicitly checking the arguments count of the invoked function.